# Highcharts, error with xAxis type logarithmic

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with my Highcharts.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lladisa/e99vm/2/).

The points between 125 250 and 500 are too close; If I add the logarithmic type on xAxis it doesn't work because I can't see the `xAxis` values.

Does someone know why I have this problem?

thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Because values for tickPositions are not strict ones, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/e99vm/3/

Change from:

```
        tickPositions: [125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 9000],
```

to:

```
        tickPositions: [1, 2, 3], // 10, 100, 1000
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, unfortunately i need to show necessarily the values 
[125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 9000] on xAxis.

Is there a way to solve this problem keeping those values?

Comment: So you need to calculate values before: `Math.log(val)/ Math.LN10`. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e99vm/4/